# c# bool.change event

Tags: c#, .net, boolean

Can I setup an event listener so that when a bool changes a function is called?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use properties in C#, then you can add any handling you want in the setter (logging, triggering an event, ...)

```
private Boolean _boolValue
public Boolean BoolValue
{
    get { return _boolValue; }
    set
    {
        _boolValue = value;
        // trigger event (you could even compare the new value to
        // the old one and trigger it when the value really changed)
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm I'm lost. Could you provide an example to get me going please?

Comment: Done :-) Properties are really good at many things. I would urge you to always use them for public data (instead of members). This makes changes or additions easier and you can specify them in interfaces, which you cannot do for members...

Answer (score 7):

Manually, Yes you can

```
public delegate void SomeBoolChangedEvent();
public event SomeBoolChangedEvent SomeBoolChanged;

private bool someBool;
public bool SomeBool
{
    get
    {
        return someBool;
    }
    set
    {
        someBool = value;
        if (SomeBoolChanged != null) 
        {
             SomeBoolChanged();
        }
    }   
}
```

Not sure however if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 6):

The important question here is: when a `bool` *what* changes?

Since `bool` is a value type you cannot pass around references to it directly. So it doesn't make sense to talk about anything like a `Changed` event on `bool` itself -- if a `bool` changes, it is *replaced* by another `bool`, not modified.

The picture changes if we 're talking about a `bool` field or property on a reference type. In this case, the accepted practice is to expose the `bool` as a property (public fields are frowned upon) and [use the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) to raise the "changed" notification.

Answer (score 5):

Look into implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. [MSDN has got a great How To on the subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx)